# Set new name for each drawn point Open Layer

Tags: openlayers

I add to the map the points. To each point I want to add new name like `'Point 1'`, `'Point 2'`, etc.. The problem is when I add the `function(){}` to the `style` it change number of `indexPoint` with every move automatically and the numbers become big. See code below and photo

```
var indexPoint = 0;
$('#MarkPoint').on('click', function(){
    map.removeLayer(vector);
    removeInteractions();
    source = new ol.source.Vector();
    indexPoint = 0;

    vector = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source: source,
        style: function(){ 
            return new ol.style.Style({
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2)'
                }),
                stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                    color: '#ffcc33',
                    width: 2
                }),
                image: new ol.style.Circle({
                    radius: 7,
                    fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                        color: '#ffcc33'
                    })
                }),               
                text:  textPoint().text              
            })              
        }
    });

    draw = new ol.interaction.Draw({
        source: source,
        type: 'Point'
    });
    map.addInteraction(draw);
    map.addLayer(vector);     

})

var textPoint = function() {
    indexPoint += 1
    var zoom = map.getView().getZoom();
    //var resolution = map.getView().getResolution();
    var font = ( zoom + 1 )
    return {
        text: new ol.style.Text({
            font: '12 px Arial',
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: '#ffd300'
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: '#000',
                width: 3
            }),
            offsetX: 20,
            offsetY: -12,
            overflow: true,
            text: 'Ponto ' + indexPoint.toString()

        })   
    }
}
```

[image: image 1]
[image: image 2]
[image: image 3]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you pass a function to a layer's 'style'-property, it's called a Style-function. A Style-function is called every single time the layer is rendered. In your example, the global variable indexPoint updates it's value on each pan, each zoom, etc.

I think you got 2 options:

Option 1: Set the number of each point as a property, and let the styleFunction read that property. You have access to the features property in a style-function because it can take the feature and the resolution as parameteres, it could look something like this:

```
  style: function(feature, resolution) {
    return new Style({
      image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 7,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({
        color: '#ffcc33'
        })
      }), 
      text: new Text({
        text: feature.get('number'),
        fill: new Fill({color: '#ffcc33'}),
      });
    });
  }
```

You can set the 'number' attribute right when the user draws the point, this can be done [this way](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/120698/openlayers-3-draw-set-name).

Option 2: Do not set a stylefunction on the layer, but rather set the style of each feature individually right when it's created

Comment: I used option 1 :) Thanks!